# Rotate , Flip Image using Jquery , css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery and css to achieve Following

1) Image Flip (Left, Right )

2) Image Rotate (Left, Right )

the following Image will explain it better.

[image]

Now I am using the following code to do so..

```
var transform = 180;
var ImgRotate = 0;


    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();    
    $('#ibtnFlipRight').click(function () {    
        var Img = $('#ImgPopUpTab2').find('img');
        $(".ImgOfPopUpTab2").css({ 'transform': 'rotateY(' + transform + 'deg)' });
        transform = transform + 180;
    });

    $('#ibtnFlipLeft').click(function () {
        var Img = $('#ImgPopUpTab2').find('img');        
        $(".ImgOfPopUpTab2").css({ 'transform': 'rotateY(' + transform + 'deg)' });
        transform = transform - 180;
    });

    $('#ibtnRotateRight').click(function () {
        ImgRotate = ImgRotate + 90;
        var Img = $('#ImgPopUpTab2').find('img');
        $(".ImgOfPopUpTab2").css({ 'transform': 'rotateZ(' + ImgRotate + 'deg)' });

    });

    $('#ibtnRotateLeft').click(function () {
        ImgRotate = ImgRotate - 90;
        var Img = $('#ImgPopUpTab2').find('img');
        $(".ImgOfPopUpTab2").css({ 'transform': 'rotateZ(' + ImgRotate + 'deg)' });
    });
```

Now let say I click on Rotate Right/Left 
and then click on Flip it overwrites the Rotate.

So I need a solution using it the user can rotate the image and can flip the same.

Thanks

Comment: Save its curresnt rotaion(degrees) and flip(true/false), in the img's attributes like data-rot="90" data-flipped="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think your problem is you cannot flip and rotate at the same time, a simple solution to this is make the images container rotate and flip the image inside it, here is a sample snippet for just a demo (save its current state using data attributes)

```js
  var FRAME = $('#frame');
 function rotate(angle)
 {
  var IMAGE = FRAME.find('img');
  var isFlipped = FRAME.data('flipped');
  if(isFlipped)angle*=-1;
  var angleNow = Number(FRAME.data('angle'));
  var newAngle = angleNow + angle;
  FRAME.data('angle',newAngle);
  IMAGE.css('transform','rotate('+newAngle+'deg)');
 }

 function flip()
 {
  var isFlipped = FRAME.data('flipped');
  FRAME.data('flipped',!isFlipped);
  if(isFlipped)FRAME.css('transform','rotateY(0deg)');
  else FRAME.css('transform','rotateY(180deg)');
 }
```

```css
#frame{
   display: inline-block;
  }
.controls {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
 <button onclick="rotate(-45)">Rotate Left</button>
 <button onclick="rotate(45)">Rotate Right</button>
 <button onclick="flip()">Flip</button>
</div>
<div id="frame" data-angle="0" data-flipped="false" >
 <img src="https://blog.xenproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Testing.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store an object indicating the current state (rotation and flip). Whenever you change the object, you re-render the transform css. What you are looking for is `rotate(x, y, z)`